# Clarity on Setting up Docker containers for django projects?

Tags: python, django, docker, containers

I'm experimenting with docker and have some basic hands-on with it. I would like to know how to structure the containers to scale in a better way.

Auth Container - 
    Using Auth0 for Authentication only. With JWT for authentication

Profile Container-
    A python app to store user profile along with MongoDB as a database. I prefer keeping this in a separate container because it will not be used much as the other services.

Blog Container-
    This is another python app that allows users to write/edit articles and uses the same MongoDB as the profile container.

My Question is how two different python apps share the authentication from the auth container.

I have developed similar monolithic apps with Django, but as a single project. I would like to do the same but both the profile and blog as different projects itself.

What kind of Structure should I follow to implement such projects?

Comment: You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). Maybe you can check this [github repo](https://github.com/ruddra/docker-django) about using django with docker(with docker compose).

Comment: @ruddra  I have done the same and have got it work. I'm curious about using two different Django projects in two different containers. sharing the same authentication system.

Comment: Well, you can certainly do that. It's not a complicated thing in perspective of Docker.

Comment: is there an example of multiple Django projects with multiple `docker-compose.yml` file that I can refer to?